# Removing headline from allheadlines if headline has keyerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a list of rss feed headlines that I'm iterating like so:

```
for hl in allheadlines:
    try:
        updated = hl[0]['updated_parsed']
    except(KeyError):
        print("updated_parsed not in this headline")
        allheadlines.remove(hl)
```

I need to check if `updated_parsed` is in each headline and if missing, remove that headline entirely. The code above runs and prints "updated_parsed not in this headline," but is not removing the headline. Any idea as to why?

Comment: can you provide a sample of `allheadlines `?

Comment: Please have a read of [Minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to remove elements from the list while using a `for` loop, Python gives you an unexpected result most of the times. The problem is that Python keeps a variable to  remember the current element, which will refer to something unexpected when the list changes from under the iterator.

A solution could be iterating over a copy of the list:

```
for hl in allheadlines[:]:
    ...
```

Or you could iterate the list back to front:

```
for hl in reversed(allheadlines):
    ....
```

Or you can create a second list where you can put all the elements that match your desired condition.

Answer (score 2):

Adding or removing elements in a `for` loop where you iterate over such a list gives an undefined behaviour in Python.

One of many possible solutions is to create a separate updated list of headlines:

```
updated_headlines = []
for hl in allheadlines:
    try:
        updated = hl[0]['updated_parsed']
        updated_headlines.append(hl)
    except(KeyError):
        print("updated_parsed not in this headline")
```

The code throwing exception is in line

```
updated = hl[0]['updated_parsed']
```

so when it throws the next line:

```
updated_headlines.append(hl)
```

is omitted and the headline with error is not added.